# JPA Criteria Query, how to join entities - Hibernate-

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have made a JPA project (using hibernate). It's a bit more complex than this, but here are 2 classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "Persons")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable= false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Integer persId;
    @Column(nullable= false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable= false, length = 50)
    private String surname;
    @Column(nullable= true, length = 50)
    private String emailAddress;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="person", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Account account;

    //private Account account;
    public Person() {
        // empty
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String surname, String emailAddress) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }


    public Integer getPersId() {
        return persId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
    //public Account getAccount() {
    //    return account;
    //}
    //public void setAccount(Account account) {
    //    this.account = account;
    //}
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [persId=" + persId + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", surname=" + surname + ", emailAddress=" + emailAddress + "]";
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PhoneNumbers")
public class PhoneNumber {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer phoneId;
    //@Column(nullable= false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    //GETSETTERS

    public Integer getPhoneId() {
        return phoneId;
    }
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    //OVERRIDES

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj instanceof PhoneNumber) {
            String num = ((PhoneNumber)obj).getPhoneNumber();
            return (num == this.phoneNumber);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return phoneNumber.hashCode();
    }

    public PhoneNumber(Person person, String phoneNumber){
        this.person = person;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Now, what I'm trying to do, is make a Criteria Query, which would give me the person who's telephone number is the same as given string.
I have written a test adding some sample data and getting it back, but I seriously can't understand how join works here.

```
CriteriaQuery<Person> query = personService.criteriaBuilder().createQuery(Person.class);
        Root<Person> pRoot = query.from(Person.class);
Join<Person, PhoneNumber> pNumbers = pRoot.join(Person_.phoneNumbers);
```

Is this a correct line? And if so, what does it do, and how do I later addres those fields in the "where" clause? Thanks in advance every1!

ps. the whole project contains more files- personService is an interface, You can assume that all it's uses are correct- its only the Criteria Queries that I'm having problem with

Comment: It is unclear what difficulties you are having with this example. This is an inner join - the default `JoinType.INNER`, when you do not use an overloaded version of the `join()` method. The query will return duplicate parent rows (`Person`), if corresponding child rows (`PhoneNumber`) in the child entity are repeated. You need `DISTINCT` to filter out possible duplicate rows from the result list or use a sub-query. The `WHERE` clause is missing which is required, since you need to fetch the result list conditionally. Please complete the query.

Comment: You are using JPA criteria. The tag [hibernate-criteria] is a different thing. Please consider removing it, if you are not dealing with Hibernate criteria.